# How can I obtain brackets with proper size on multiple lines using the {multline} environment?

Tags: brackets, delimiters, multline

My code is of the form

```
\begin{multline}
\left[ \frac{foo}{bar} \\ foo \right]
\end{multline}
```

This code gives an error for missing \right. etc. To remedy this, I used this code

```
\begin{multline}
\left[ \frac{foo}{bar} \right. \\\left. foo \right]
\end{multline}
```

However, in this code, the right ] bracket is small and is not the same size as the left [.
Please let me know if a solution to this exists.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually scaling, i.e. `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`. There is no other way. `\left...\right` has to look at its contents in order to auto scale, and thus line breaks are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I offer to use the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace,right=\empheqrbrace]{align}
        \frac{foo}{bar} \\
        foo
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

And, without numbering (`align*`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `[c]` indicates center alignment of the stack.  `[l]` and `[r]` are also options there.  Additionally, the stack gap is (by default) 3pt between items.  That can be changed with an appropriate specification.  Finally, the `[` and `]` are merely scaled to fit the stack.  You can use an optional argument to `\scaleleftright` as a width limiting feature, if the width of the brackets is too large.

EDITED to show two approaches, depending on how you want your math axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[
math-axis 
\scaleleftright{[}
{\Shortstack[c]{$\displaystyle\frac{foo}{bar}$ $foo$}}
{]}
\]
\def\stackalignment{l}
\[
math-axis 
\scaleleftright{[}
{\stackanchor[5pt]{$\displaystyle\frac{foo}{bar}$}{$foo$}}
{]}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]